# Why the python regex pattern fails to match when append a dollar($)?

Tags: python, regex

Here's a small code, using python 3.4

```
import re
path_pattern=r'(([^\W]|[.~%$])+)'
re.search(path_pattern+'$','./').string
```

It will report `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'` on execution.

If I remove the `+'$'` in the code, It works,

```
import re
path_pattern=r'(([^\W]|[.~%$])+)'
re.search(path_pattern,'./').string
```

As far as I know, `$` is for matching the end of string, but why isn't it working here?

Comment: Your `./` contains `/` that is not matched, thus, there is no match at the end of the string. What are your requirements? (BTW, `[^\W]` = `\w`)

Comment: I feel like it matches the actual character in a character set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex cannot match the / character in your string, and only . is matched.

When you use $ in your regex, it cannot match at all. When you remove it, it matches but only with ".".

Answer (score 2):

If your explore your regex `path_pattern` at https://regex101.com/, you'll find it only matches `.`, so after you append `$`, it'll match nothing, and `re.search` returns `None` if no position in the string matches the pattern, that's why you get the error.

Check it out here:

```
>>> path_pattern=r'(([^\W]|[.~%$])+)'
>>> r = re.search(path_pattern + "$",'./')
>>> print(r)
None
```